# Setting a function to call a column within a data set

Tags: r, function

I have been searching for a correct way to call a column within a dataset by using a function.
The problem is, that I have multiple columns where the date and time are within one cell, for each month. So I wanted to write a function to split them, by just enter the arguments in the function. Therefor I don't have to write that code each and every time, but just the function. I wrote down the column names and the function below.

(**DataFrame**, **SourceColumn**: Where the data is stored in the column, **TargetDate**: Where the date needs to go  **TargetTime**: Where the time needs to go)

```
test <- function(DataFrame, SourceColumn, TargetDate, TargetTime)
DataFrame$TargetDate <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(DataFrame$Source), " "), "[", 1)


DataFrame$TargetTime <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(DataFrame$Source), " "), "[", 2)
```

I hoped that calling this function would work like this:

```
test <- (Agenda_Feb, date_time, date, time)
```

Unfortunately it doesn't. It says replacement has 0 rows, data has 139. The code works, because I used it already with the the real names without the function.

Could any help me? Thanks in advance!

Robin

Comment: Function works in own environment and does not interact with anything beyond it. What you can do though is make function read in data and return data.

Comment: To call a function, you'd do like this `results <- test(Agenda_Feb, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

The idea here is to read in vector of interest and return dataframe of multiple columns that you can `cbind()` with initial dataframe. You can not directly manipulate objects in Global environment with a function.

With my simplified example:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c("a b", "b c", "c d", "d e"))
split_cols <- function(data) {
  return(data.frame(b = sapply(strsplit(as.character(data), " "), "[", 1),
                    c = sapply(strsplit(as.character(data), " "), "[", 2))) 
}

df <- cbind(df, split_cols(df$a))
```